# NotificationCompat does not work properly

Tags: android, notifications

I have a problem when creating a notification.
I have to create a notification which should arise 1 day before the date of an event. However, the notification appears immediately after the event.
The setWhen () and setShowWhen () are set correctly.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("Event")
            .setContentText(heritage.getTitle())
            .setSubText("Tap to see event")
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(setDateNotification(startDate, time))
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the functionality of those functions. As per documentation `setWhen` shows when the event occurs, not when the notification has to be shown and `setShowWhen` shows the date set by `setWhen` in the notification itself if true was passed. Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Comment: Post the `AlarmManager` code too.